# onNewIntent is not being called

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm trying pass over push data from receiver to the activity using an Intent and it doesn't seem to work. Any idea why? Here is my implementation:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!--
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="com.appName.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.appName.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="RB"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="com.appName.appExtension">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="API_KEY"
        />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="RB"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.appNamw.RouteView"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_route_view"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">

    </activity>
    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.appName.ParseReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.appName" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

**ParseReceiver**

```
package com.appName;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.util.Log;

import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
import com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class ParseReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {
    private final String TAG = "Push_Notify";

    @Override
    public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onPushOpen triggered!");

    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(intent);
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    mainIntent.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
    mainIntent.putExtra("method", "updateStatus");

    mainIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);


    JSONObject pushData;

    String alert;
    try {
        pushData = new JSONObject(intent.getStringExtra(ParseSupplyReceiver.KEY_PUSH_DATA));
        alert = pushData.getString("alert");
        String name = pushData.getString("name");
        String contactNumber = pushData.getString("contactNumber");
        String durationText = pushData.getString("duration");

        mainIntent.putExtra("alert", alert);
        mainIntent.putExtra("pushData", new PushData(name, contactNumber, durationText));

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.i(TAG,"JSONException: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    context.startActivity(mainIntent);

   }
}
```

**PushData.java**

```
package com.appName;


import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;


public class PushData implements Parcelable{
   String name;
   String contactNumber;
   String durationText;


   public PushData (String name,String contactNumber,String durationText ){
  /*
   * Reconstruct from the Parcel. Keep same order as in writeToParcel()
   */

       this.name = name;
       this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
       this.durationText = durationText;
  }

  public PushData(Parcel source) {
      name = source.readString();
      contactNumber = source.readString();
      durationText = source.readString();

  }


    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(contactNumber);
        dest.writeString(durationText);
   }

   @Override
   public int describeContents() {
      return 0;
   }

   public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {

      public PushData createFromParcel(Parcel source) {

          return new PushData(source);
      }

      public PushData[] newArray(int size) {

          return new PushData[size];
      }

  };
}
```

Implementation of onNewIntent in MainActivity:

```
 @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);

    if (intent.getStringExtra("method").equals("updateStatus")) {
        alertString = intent.getStringExtra("alert");
        pushData = intent.getParcelableExtra("pushData");
        updateStatus();
    }
}



public void updateStatus() {


    if (pushData != null) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("name", pushData.name);
        editor.putString("contactNumber", pushData.contactNumber);
        editor.putString("duration", pushData.durationText);
    }
}
```

May I know what is wrong here? I have done an similar implementation on another app and it works completely fine.

Comment: What if you change FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK  to FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP?

Comment: mainIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |  FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); fixed this. Can you move this to answer? so that I can accept

Comment: Glad to hear it. Posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag to your intent
(see [onNewIntent(Intent intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent))).

Answer (score 1):

I think it`s not about your FLAG,but your activity`s launchmode;

It seems like that this method only be called when it`s launchmode is singleTask or sigleTop;

Answer (score 0):

You also have a spelling mistake in your Manifest. Change

```
<activity android:name="com.appNamw.RouteView"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_route_view"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

TO

```
<activity android:name="com.appName.RouteView"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_route_view"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```